# Rendering uniform grayscale colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to display a numerical matrix in matplotlib with same colors for equal values, the following code snippet for example produces different shade for the same number (e.g: 7.5 in the top left corner)

```
res = ax.imshow(np.array(matrix_data), cmap=plt.cm.gray,interpolation='nearest'
                )
```

I want to display the same shade for equal values , How is that possible, the values are in red in the below figure?

[image: matrixvalues]

Comment: just give the numbers matrix as a 2d array to the imshow(), this usually should do the trick already. Also, try pcolor(), which might be more suited for this task.

Comment: ok got it the numbers itself were incorrectly normalized

Comment: Please answer (and accept when it will let you) your own question.